# Swift - Convert MP4/M4A to MP3

Tags: iphone, swift, mp3, converters, m4a

I have NSData which contains M4A\AAC audio file and I want to convert it to MP3 stream in iOS Swift.
I don't want to use the file system.

I have tried a lot of near by examples but didn't succeed to solve this issue.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide some code you have tried

Comment: What are those examples you are referring to?